# Meteor subscription connections

Tags: meteor

I was wondering how meteor subscriptions work. Say we publish more than one item

```
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {..});
Meteor.publish("keys", function () {..});
Meteor.publish("cars", function () {..});
Meteor.publish("assets", function () {..});
Meteor.publish("employees", function () {..});
Meteor.publish("inventory", function () {..});
```

and the corresponding subscriptions in the client set.

Meteors reactivity ensures that when a new record is updated that the client also gets updated in real-time. So this means theres a persistent connection down to the user

Does each of these use up one persistent connection between the server and client for all data or does each have its own (websocket/comet/..) connection (so 6 total?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one livedata stream connection from the web page to the server.  The connection is shared between all subscriptions and method calls.